# Connecting to Internet on Windows Mobile with C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

When you start Internet Explorer on Windows Mobile and you don't have connection yet, Explorer automatically starts connecting to the Internet. I would like to do the same thing in C#.

I want my application to detect if I am connected to the Internet. If i am not then it should connected itself automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exercise your P/Invoke muscles with the the [Windows Mobile Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx). Not hard at all.

Comment: can you give me a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SystemState objects to determine your current connection status and the ConnectionManager if you'd like to connect.